# Identifying a Modular Exponent

Tags: modular-arithmetic

Let's say I'm given a number. 
I am now asked to determine if this number is of the form : $a^{b}$ mod $N$ .
Unfortunately the parameters are such that I cannot perform a discrete logarithm in feasible time.
$a$ and $N$ are known (and large) natural numbers with $a<b<N$.
$a$ is a prime number. $N$ is composite. Nothing is known about $b$.
What are some mathematical tests I can perform to determine this?

Comment: This is basically the Discrete Logarithm Problem. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_logarithm

Comment: Welcome to Maths SX! Is $N$ prime? If not, you may try to simplify the problem using the *Chinese remainder theorem*.

Comment: Thank you @Bernard! I've edited the question to include those details. N is composite.
Thanks @JoshuaWang. I am aware of the discrete logarithm problem but N is chosen such that computing the discrete logarithm isn't feasible.

Comment: The number $c$ can be expressed in that way if GCD(N,c) = 1.